# tried to access class kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker from class androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm getting `java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker from class androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion` with the following test, why?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class DBTest {

  @Test
  @Throws(Exception::class)
  fun basicOperations() = runBlocking  {
    val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
    val db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
    db.favDao().insertFav(Fav("whatever"))
    assertEquals("whatever", db.favDao().getFav("whatever"))
    db.favDao().deleteFav(Fav("whatever"))
    assertEquals(null, db.favDao().getFav("whatever"))
    db.close()
  }
}
```

I pretty much just copied [from the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db).

I'm using the latest `room-coroutines` as there was recent media coverage about it from Google.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, I have filed an issue with the Room team here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124781244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3/21/19 a fix was introduced in the snapshot of Robolectric, it should be included in future releases:

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commit/6d246391fdaac92968811bc83e1afb057e6f93a3

The cause was due to an internal annotation on the companion object of CoroutinesRoom class.